# How to set edit Text values to null in different activities?

Tags: java, android

First off, I have two activities. One is the MainActivity and the other is a NoteEditorActivity. I created a table in my NoteEditorActivity with about 40 edit texts. However, when I add a note in the app from the menu, it creates another note but does not refresh the values in the edit texts. I was wondering how to store all the values in an array list from the edit Texts and refresh all the values to null when a note is added.

I've tried a lot of other things, but this method may be promising.

This is the Main Activity

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.add_note_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.add_note) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TableNoteEditorActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.NoteLab", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        HashSet<String> set = (HashSet<String>) sharedPreferences.getStringSet("notes", null);

        HashSet<String> tableInputSet = (HashSet<String>) sharedPreferences.getStringSet("tableInput", null);

        if (set == null) {

            notes.add("Example");

        } else {

            notes = new ArrayList(set);
        }

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TableNoteEditorActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("noteId", i);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

This is the TableNoteEditorActivity

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_table_note_editor);

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleViewInput);

        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        et4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        et5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        et6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        et7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        et8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        et9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        et10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        et11 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        et12 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView12);

        loadSavedPreferences();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        noteId = intent.getIntExtra("noteId", -1);

        if(noteId != -1){

            editText.setText(MainActivity.notes.get(noteId));

        } else {

            MainActivity.notes.add("");
            noteId = MainActivity.notes.size() - 1;
            MainActivity.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                MainActivity.notes.set(noteId, String.valueOf(charSequence));
                MainActivity.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.NoteLab", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                HashSet<String> set = new HashSet(MainActivity.notes);

                sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("notes", set).apply();

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
    }
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48EB4HeP1kI&list=LLhpPM8FLd5uST7RfQa_riQg&index=3&t=1842s

I watched this to create the base of the note app.

Comment: Hi @Jeff! Your notes instance is a List<String>? Can you also please post the code you are using to initialize the arrayadapter with the empty list initially in your NoteEditorActivity class?

Comment: My notes instance is an ArrayList<String>.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with your second question?